# What happens in hardware during error handling in for this ARM microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, arm

There is a function called **__disable_irq();** in ARM microcontrollers CMSIS library and does something which I don't understand.

It is defined as:

```
__STATIC_FORCEINLINE void __disable_irq(void)
{
  __ASM volatile ("cpsid i" : : : "memory");
}
```

It is always under Error_Handler fucntion if you use HAL library:

```
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}
```

For example when initializing uart:

```
  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */
```

What really happens here hardware wise if HAL_OK returns false? Does the microcontroller reset? What does __disable_irq() do?

Comment: What is the ARM microcontroller you’re referring to? Be it Cortex M0.3.4 or 7  may affect the answer.

Comment: M4 at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__disable_irq()` disables all interrupts, with the exception of a few non-maskable ones, preventing interrupt handlers from running as a result of stimuli such as timers, pin changes, incoming I/O, etc.

When this is followed with a `while(1) {}`, this intentionally locks up the processor until it is reset. This is preferable to having a program that's still running or handling interrupts, in an unknown state, after an unrecoverable error.

Comment: I don't think that the Cortex-M has FIQ interrupts.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks, removed that section